# I'm using Tabulas in a for loop; getting this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py

I'm using a for loop to work through an entire folder of pdfs, which are converted to csv files.

```
import tabula
import os
import pandas as pd
files_in_directory = os.listdir()

filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".pdf")]
print(range(len(filtered_files)))
for file in range(len(filtered_files)):
    print(file-1)
    print(range(len(filtered_files)))

    print(file)
    print(filtered_files[file-1])
    df = tabula.read_pdf(filtered_files[file-1])
    csv_name = filtered_files[file-1] + '.csv'
    df[file-1].to_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is my log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/braydenyates/Documents/Band PDFS/csv_converter.py", line 16, in <module>
    df[file-1].to_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code appears to run two of the sixty-three files in the folder, then ends due to this error.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of PDF files you have does not necessarily equal to the number of dataframes tabula manages to extract from one of the PDFs. `file` represents the Nth file while `df` is a list of dataframes actually. Therefore `df[file-1]` is something that's not really sensible to use. Loop through the dataframes and same them individually or whatever is intended.

Here, have a more pythonic and simpler solution:

```
import tabula
import os
import pandas as pd

files_in_directory = os.listdir()
filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".pdf")]

for file in filtered_files:
    dfs = tabula.read_pdf(file)

    for nth_frame, df in enumerate(dfs, start=1):
        csv_name = f'{file}_{nth_frame}.csv'
        df.to_csv(csv_name, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I need to brush up on my for loops! I think my mistake in thinking is that I thought that 'file' was an integer that worked through the enumerated 'filtered_files'. I didn't realize when you ran a for loop through an array, that it was actually using the values themselves. Thanks for your help and I'll be sure to review and learn from it!